# Neural Network Robust to Random Error in training set

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, robust

I have read that deep learning algorithms are robust to random errors in the training set - is anyone able to explain why this is?

Comment: Are you looking for a proof or for empirical evidence?

Comment: Ps it's not always true. If your task is multiclass classification, you have strong class imbalance and there are classes which have proportionally much more wrong labels that others, the model won't be that robust. But, compared to other ML, it's *incredibly* robust.

Comment: Hey @DeltaIV thanks for this. Your example makes sense. I guess I am looking for a theoretical explanation as to why a neural network might be more robust (than other ML models) to random errors in the training set. For example, whether this is because of activation function or the way weights adjust etc.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately I can't help with the answer, and I doubt anyone can. We all know well that deep Convnets tolerate large amounts of noise in the labels (there's a metric ton of papers on this topic), and we also know ways to make them robust to so-called *structured* noise. But I don't know of any paper giving a convincing theoretical explanation. There are the usual hand-wavy, post-hoc fables people tell to convince themselves they know what's going on, but that's just make-believe, like the fact that BatchNorm improves performance by "reducing covariate shift": 1/

Comment: 2/ it has been proven that this justification is false. If you're ok with a general survey of the robustness to noise phenomenon, I can write one, but if you actually need theory, I'd be surprised to see anyone giving you a *solid* theoretical answer.